# How to handle an interrupt?

Tags: assembly, interrupt-handling

I have a task to write a program which handles the division by zero exception. I'm having a hard time finding information about that. As I understand, I need to change the 0th entry in interrupt vector table, but how do I do that? I see there is a LIDT instruction, but wouldn't I have to write the whole table then?

Note, I'll be working in 16 bit mode.

Comment: Divide by Zero is a fault, not an interrupt.

Comment: LIDT is needed when the CPU is operating in the protected mode (which can be "16-bit" too). What is the mode that you want to handle the exception in? Protected, real or virtual 8086?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you mean "real mode" by 16-bit mode, the interrupt vector table is simply located starting at linear address 0, see the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table#Real_mode) entry. So it's a matter of getting the old 4-byte far pointer from `[0000:0000]` so it can be restored later (or chained) and overwriting the entry with your own handler.

If you're using DOS you can use [`INT 21h/AH=25h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2602.htm) to set the interrupt vector and `INT 21h/AH=35h` to retrieve the old entry.